# After bundling with webpack, correcting Javascript errors as elements are not present in the current page

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I am currently using webpack in a project that was created without any bundler. It has a few html pages and some javascript files associated with each page.

After bundling these files I find that I get errors because "element A" is not present on "page B", therefore it throws an error.

What is the best approach here? Checking with an "if" on every event listener is a good practice? It seems kind of wrong to me. Is there a better way? Creating an Object with all of the DOM elements and importing it maybe?

I guess I'm asking if there is a best practice for this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have three options:

1. Create per-page bundles that only include the scripts relevant to that page. If there is a lot of script code that's used by multiple pages, this means each bundle will include that script code; if the user moves page-to-page within your project, they'll re-download those common bits as parts of each individual bundle. Those redundant parts of the bundles will consume more bandwidth and cache space (again, assuming a page-to-page navigation within your project) than option #2.
2. Create one uber-bundle that all pages use, and do those checks you mentioned for whether an element exists, which can easily be encapsulated in a function. This means that a user will load script code for pages he/she may not ever visit.
3. A combination of the two: Use two bundles on each page, one containing all the common script used by all (or most) pages, the other containing the per-page scripts.

Which you go for is entirely up to you. Things to consider are the degree of page-to-page navigation in your project, the overall size of the bundles, using more or less bandwidth and cache space, and probably a few things I haven't thought to list. :-)

Comment: I will split the code into different bundles then, feels like a good approach. Thank you.